# How can I access the streaming camera video as bitmap or ByteBuffer in Android studio without saving it?(Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.3

I am building an app in Android studio in Java where I want to access realtime video from camera without saving it and get it as a ByteBuffer. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It Depends on the API you use (CameraX, Camera2).
If you use Camera2 API the general flow would be:

1. Open a Camera:

```
val manager = getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
manager.openCamera(cameraId, cameraStateCallback, cameraHandler)
```

2. Wait for the camera to open:

```
private val cameraStateCallback: CameraDevice.StateCallback = object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    override fun onOpened(cameraDevice: CameraDevice) {
        //Start a capture session
    }

    override fun onDisconnected(cameraDevice: CameraDevice) {
        cameraOpenCloseLock.release()
        cameraDevice.close()
    }

    override fun onError(cameraDevice: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
        cameraOpenCloseLock.release()
        cameraDevice.close()
    }
}
```

3. Then start a capture session, and using ImageReader to receive images.

You can check [this project](https://github.com/gioravered/camera_image_reader) for a small basic working example of the entire flow.